# from each one-third part that eliminated in construting the Cantor set pick a point, what apout the resulting set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

During constructing the cantor set, pick up a point from the one-third that eliminated. if we call the set of this points A, then what is the internal of A? is the complement of A countable?

Comment: If I understand your idea correctly, it is easy to see that $A$ is countable. This should answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each stage of the construction of the middle-thirds Cantor set we remove only finitely many intervals, so there are countably infinitely many removed intervals. Your set $A$ contains one point from each of them, so $A$ is countable. Every non-empty open subset of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable — in fact of cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ — so the interior of $A$ is empty.

For each $a\in A$ let $I_a$ be the removed interval containing $a$. The family $\{I_a:a\in A\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of open sets, each containing exactly one member of $A$, so $A$ is a discrete set in $\Bbb R$.

Now let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set. If $x\in C$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is an $a\in A$ such that $a\in I_a\subseteq(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$, so even though $A$ is discrete, every point of $C$ is a limit point of $A$. In fact, the closure of $A$ is $A\cup C$.